# how to use case statements efficiently

Tags: sql, case-statement

I have repetitive and hardcoded query like this. Following is just a tip of the iceberg. there are multiple similar statements (not shown below).Is there a way to make it short?

```
Create table analysis as
Select name,
case when gender = 'M'  then A  else ' ' end) as MA,
case when gender = 'M'  then B  else . end) as MB,
case when gender = 'M'  then C  else . end) as MC,
case when gender = 'F'  then A  else ' ' end) as FA,
case when gender = 'F'  then B  else . end) as FB,
case when gender = 'F'  then C  else . end) as FC
FROM student;
```

Comment: provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: That doesn't look like it will work.  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please, add a tag

Comment: What is `else .`???

Comment: ' ' is blank(space) and (. ) is period ( both indicating missing/unavailable value).

Comment: I am using  proc sql in base SAS.